# How does the MuleSoft's Salesforce Connector v10.13.x manage login requests

Tags: salesforce, mulesoft

The service account SF user we have setup on our Salesforce connector is hitting the "login rate exceeded" (3,600 per hour) governor limit.

The connector is configured in a MuleSoft app hosted on MuleSoft RTF, which is a service containing a set of APIs that downstream applications can use to interface with Salesforce. We've configured the Salesforce connector configs to use:

- basic authentication
- no configured connection & login request timeouts (0 seconds)
- no reconnection strategy

Within an hour, we're seeing volumes of 70k API requests to this Mulesoft app, but after configuring this debug logging level on the SF connector:

```
logging.level.org.mule.extension.salesforce=DEBUG
```

And that all SF component calls within that hour are sharing the same sessionId (85k component requests), but also see that there are about 200 ish soap login requests.

We don't understand what causes the SF connector to make a SOAP login request that contributes to that limit we're seeing. And we're hoping to understand that so we can optimize our implementation and avoid hitting that 3,600 logins per hour salesforce limit.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other applications using the same credentials?

Comment: @Aled,we do have other application sharing the credentials for this Salesforce user, but the others have fairly low volumes.
What we're seeing when enabled the Salesforce Connector DEBUG logging levels is that the majority of our requests are sharing the same sessionId (across 70k SF component requests in an hour), but there are still extraneous login soap calls being sent (200-400 in an hour).

 

--

Any insight into why these extraneous login attempts are being made?? We're not seeing a new session tokens/Ids being used in requests after these extraneous soap login attempt callouts.

Comment: You would need to share more configurations and logs . It is possible that stackoverflow is not the best match for troubleshooting this kind of issue because of the interactions that may be required.